# How to optimize for loop in c by using square root (perfect, abundant, deficient)

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, optimization, big-o

Note: I left out irrelevant code

So I am currently working on CCC 1996 P1, and the whole purpose of this problem is to be able to compute whether an integer input is a perfect, deficient, or abundant number. The code I have listed above works however, I think it is too slow. The code, iterates through every number in order to find perfect divisors, which I think is too inefficient. Anyway, I have been thinking about this for awhile, but cant seem to come up with any ways to optimize this code.

I read online that you could replace i < n, with i < sqrt(n) and then switch the line in which score is added to s += i + (n/i), or something of the sorts, however, this doesn't seem to work for me. Any suggestions on what I could do to get more efficient code and decrease the run time, because currently, the program runs for too long before reaching an output. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Also, a number is defined as perfect if the sum of all its perfect divisors equal the number. A number is defined as abundant if the sum of all its perfect divisors > the number. A number is defined as deficient if the sum of all its perfect divisors < the number. The number itself does not count as a perfect divisor.

I am not too familiar with Big-O notation.

Also, a number is defined as perfect if the sum of all its perfect divisors equal the number. A number is defined as abundant if the sum of all its perfect divisors > the number. A number is defined as deficient if the sum of all its perfect divisors < the number. The number itself does not count as a perfect divisor.

Comment: Well, one thing right off the bat that I can see that would speed this up is to compute `sqrt(numInput)` ahead of time, store it in a variable, and then refer to that variable in the rest of the algorithm. The way you have it, it's recomputing that square root over and over again  every time you go through the loop, and then recomputing it *again* when you add it to `score`.

Comment: Alright thanks! Yeah that makes sense, it seems pretty pointless to countless compute the square root. However, I dont know why the square roots aren't working. In theory the modification makes sense to me.

Comment: Suppose the candidate number is N.  The divisor 1 is a special case because N is not counted.  All other factors come in pairs, F1 and F2, where F1 ≤ √N and F2 ≥ √N.  Your computation doesn't seem to be handling this correctly.  For N = 25, you have 1 and 5 as factors (not 1 and 5 and 5, I believe), so you have to be careful.  For N = 28, you have 1, 2 & 14, 4 & 7 as the factors.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace

```
score += i + ((sqrt(numInput))/i);
```

with

```
result = numInput/i;
score += (result == i || i == 1)? i : i + result;
```

The idea is that for each factor less than the square root, the result is always larger or equal to the square root, and is also a factor.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input. However, the code presented isn't working as intended. I am not sure why. Any ideas? However, what you wrote makes sense. I am just unsure why it isn't working. For instance, it tells me  6 is abundant.

Comment: I edited the answer, I think it might be due to the first loop when i is 1,